# Da dove deriva l'uso di franco come moneta generica?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Sin da quando ero piccolo ho sempre sentito usare nella mia zona d'origine (Veneto, nel Trevigiano verso Venezia) la parola *Franco* come sinonimo di *Lira* e poi di *Euro*. Ad esempio

> Gli ha fatto pagare duemila franchi per la mela
>
> Non vale neanche due franchi

(In onestà le frasi sono di solito pronunciate in un ibrido di italiano e veneto, ma l'uso è sufficientemente comune da essere passato nella lingua italiana).

Vedi anche, nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/franco3/):

> **franco** [...] Nel linguaggio fam., o region. è stato usato anche come sinon. di *lira* (italiana), o soldi in generale: *il libro mi è costato pochi franchi*.

Per quello che riesco a capire, il franco è stato usato in zona solo durante la breve occupazione napoleonica, duecento anni fa, e non capisco come possa aver lasciato un'impressione talmente forte nell'uso collettivo.

**Q:** Qual è il motivo storico che ha portato a quest'uso della parola *franco*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secondo questo articolo da [Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schei) deriva più dalla dominazione austriaca che da quella francese:

> La parola franco, è stata usata per indicare una somma di denaro, associata più alle vecchie lire che all'euro, ma ancora in uso. Per cui trenta franchi erano trenta lire; 'na carta da mìłe (franchi) era una banconota da mille lire, ma rimane che averghe un franco significa ancora oggi "avere dei soldi". ***Il termine deriva da un'altra moneta austriaca, che riportava l'abbreviazione Franc., indicante il nome dell'imperatore Francesco Giuseppe.***

[image]

[Francesco Giuseppe: 4 ducati](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducato_(moneta))
Österreich - Dukat (vierfach), 1915 (Nachprägung).JPG
Al dritto: FRANC.IOS.I. D.G. AVSTRIAE IMPERATOR
***AV 1915
È identica a quelle emesse a Venezia dal 1864 al 1865***

[Note storiche](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regno_Lombardo-Veneto://):

> Proseguendo nella strada già tracciata sotto il dominio francese, dal 1822 il Lombardo-Veneto conobbe una radicale trasformazione anche in cambio monetario.
>
> Fu Francesco Giuseppe ad apportare le prime variazioni nel sistema monetario Lombardo-Veneto: egli infatti eliminò il 1/4 di lira austriaca, sostituendolo con una moneta in rame da 15 centesimi, aggiungendone anche una da 10 centesimi. Successivamente alla Seconda guerra d'indipendenza, nel Veneto entrò in vigore come moneta spicciola il soldo e i 5/10.
>
> Il governo austriaco, inoltre, abolì definitivamente tutta una serie di zecche minori che già si trovavano poco attive sul finire del Settecento e sotto l'amministrazione di Maria Teresa e Giuseppe II, mantenendo attive unicamente le zecche di Milano e Venezia.
>
> ***Parallelamente a questa circolazione di monete, erano usate come monete di libero scambio anche quelle dell'Impero Austriaco (austriaca e ungherese)***, che seguivano una tipologia di monetazione differente: il calibro in questi casi era costituito dal peso effettivo del metallo della moneta.

Comment: Che bizzarro! Sono anche sorpreso che ci sia una voce di Wikipedia per *schei*... :). Preferirei però di trovare delle referenze più affidabili di una pagina di Wikipedia senza citazioni (anche se la teoria sembra molto credibile)

Comment: @Denis Nardin - in realtà la trovi anche in Treccani -    http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schei/

Comment: Sì, avevo notato. La voce del Treccani però non riporta l'etimologia di *franco*.

Comment: Ok,    cancello tutto. Come non detto.

Comment: No, non cancellare. È un'ottima risposta!

Comment: Gio, se posso permettermi, non c'è bisogno di cancellare una risposta se non è perfetta. La teoria che proponi (presa da Wikipedia) è plausibile. In un mondo perfetto qualcuno troverebbe delle fonti più attendibili, ma in mancanza di esse anche solo presentare la teoria ha un valore.

Comment: Siccome sono completamente d'accordo con @DenisNardin, mi sono presa la libertà di "undelete" (non so come dirlo in italiano) la risposta.

Comment: @Gio Nella voce del Treccani c'è un errore: nessuno di noi veneti direbbe “gli schei” nemmeno parlando italiano, ma sempre e solo “i schei”. Credo anch'io alla derivazione di franco da “Franc.” sulle monete; la dominazione francese è stata troppo breve.

Comment: @egreg - non penso sua un errore. La parola presa in considerazione  e’ “schei” non l'espressione dialettale  “i schei”. Per cui l'uso della preposizione “gli” e’ corretta in questo caso. Gli esempi sono in italiano, solo “schei” e’ dialettale.

Comment: @Gio Come quando sento “gli gnocchi”, “gli schei” mi fa venire, come minimo, la pelle d'oca. `;-)`

Comment: @Gio Possiamo discutere finché vogliamo delle regole, ma nessun parlante nativo che userebbe la parola *schei* la precederebbe con *gli*, mi sa che questo è un caso dove la pratica val di più della grammatica ;).